# Classifying Ideal Class Group

Tags: group-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, ideal-class-group

I wish to show that the ideal class group of the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-199}]$ is the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_9$ for some practice identifying ideal class groups. I know there is a way to solve this by using binary quadratic forms, but I want to classify the group using ideals and ideal classes only. Here is a summary of some of  the progress I have made:

(**1**) Since $-199 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we see that the algebraic integers are $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-199}}{2}] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x) = x^2 - x + 50)$

(**2**) Calculating the Minkowski bound, I need to check whether $2,3,5,7$ split in  $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-199}}{2}]$. I found that all but 3 split.

(**3**) Here, $(2) = PP^{*}$, $(5) = QQ^{*}$ and $(7) = SS^{*}$, where $P = (2, \frac{1 + \sqrt{-199}}{2})$, $Q = (5, \frac{1 + \sqrt{-199}}{2})$, and $S = (7, 3 - \frac{1 + \sqrt{-199}}{2})$. I determined that these prime ideals do not equal their conjugate prime ideals.

(**4**) Finally I determined that the order of $[P], [Q], [S]$ are 9,9, and 3 respectively. Is there a way for me to write $[Q], [S]$ as powers of $[P]$? If I can, then I would be able to achieve my goal, but I do not know how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not checked your calculations and will just assume them to be correct.

By using the Minkowski bound, you can deduce that any ideal class contains an integral ideal of norm smaller than $9$.

Now recall that the norm is multiplicative and any integral ideal can be written uniquely as the product of prime ideals. Additionally $[P]$ is of order $9$ in the ideal class group, so by Lagrange's theorem the cardinality of the Class group is divisible by $9$. Now you can show that there are less than $18$ different ideals of small enough norm that you can generate as products of the prime ideals of norm less than $9$.

Thus the class number is $9$. Since it contains elements of order $9$ the class group is cyclic and hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks. I made some progress in the meantime and determined that $[S] = [P]^6$ or $[P]^3 = [S]$. Now I suspect that $[P] = [Q]$, i.e there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $P = \lambda*Q$, but I am not sure how to find one. Any suggestions?

Comment: That is not what I would try to do. Just count the number of possible products of $P,P*,Q,Q*,S,S*$ with small enough norm (i.e. $<9$). I.e. what norm does $PP*$ have? What about $PP$?